# Append iframe to multiple nodes simultaneously

Tags: javascript

I have a webpage with multiple youtube videos, all within their own sections. For GDPR compliance, these videos cannot be loaded until the user accepts a cookie consent by clicking a button. Each video section has its own GDPR compliance message and acceptance button. I want any single button click to remove the GDPR compliance message and append an iframe for all video sections on the page. i.e. If there are three video sections, clicking any one button will append an iframe and load the video for all three sections. So far, I am only able to have a button click affect a single page element, with the following error resulting for any additional sections/nodes:

'Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.'

What is the cause of this error? I looked at other questions regarding this error, and could not ascertain how it applies to my code.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
function addVideoEmbed() {
  let containers = document.querySelectorAll(".youtube-container");
  let wrappers = document.querySelectorAll(".youtube-wrapper");
  let buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".gdpr-acceptance-button");
  let iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
  let youtubeSources = [
    "videoLink1",
    "videoLink2",
    "videoLink3"
  ];

  for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    let container = containers[i];
    let button = buttons[i];
    let wrap = wrappers[i];
    let source = youtubeSources[i];

    button.addEventListener("click", function () {
      // set iframe attributes
      iframe.setAttribute(
        "style",
        "width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute;"
      );
      iframe.setAttribute("src", source);
      iframe.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
      // remove all in container
      container.removeChild(wrap);
      // add iframe to container
      container.appendChild(iframe);
    });
  }
}
addVideoEmbed();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using JQuery. Yet here's an attemp

```js
let containers = document.querySelectorAll(".youtube-container");
let wrappers = document.querySelectorAll(".youtube-wrapper");
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".gdpr-acceptance-button");
let youtubeSources = [
  "videoLink1",
  "videoLink2",
  "videoLink3"
];
for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    let button = buttons[i];

    button.addEventListener("click", function () {

    for (j = 0; j < buttons.length; j++) {
      let container = containers[j];
      let wrap = wrappers[j];
      let source = youtubeSources[j];

      let iframe = document.createElement("iframe");

      iframe.setAttribute(
        "style",
        "width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute;"
      );
      iframe.setAttribute("src", source);
      iframe.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
      // remove all in container
      container.removeChild(wrap);
      // add iframe to container
      container.appendChild(iframe);
    }

    });
}
```

Comment: That did it. I tried adding another for loop before, but I must have junked it up because it wasn't working for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should look into alternate array methods if you want to make your code more concise. querySelectorAll returns a Node List, which is not an Array but can be converted so that standard array methods can be applied to it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll

Arrays/methods:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array